# Can't send multipart file in Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, multipart, form-data

When trying to send a file to Spring boot server from Angular, the file is not sent as Multipart file. I had a similar problem 2 days ago with the same code, but after trying to find the problem and return to the current code, everything started working again. As you can see not for long. When I'm sending a file via Postman everything works fine. I tried to add other headers like Content-Type or Accept, but nothing worked. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Here Angular code:

addProduct.html

```
          <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="imageFile" style="width: 100%">Add Photo</label>
              <input type="file" id="imageFile" (change)="onFileChanged($event)">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addProduct()">Add product</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

addProduct.ts

```
public onFileChanged(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
      console.log(this.selectedFile);
  }

  addProduct(){
    const formData  = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.type);
    this.productService.uploadImage(formData).subscribe(
      response => {
              if (response.status === 200) {
                this.handleResponseImage(response);
                this.productService.addProduct(this.product).subscribe(res => {
                  console.log(res);
                });
              } else {
                console.log('error');
              }
        }
      );
  }
```

service.ts

```
  uploadImage(imageData: FormData){
    const api = API_URL + 'products/imageUpload';
    return this.http.post(api, imageData, {observe: 'response'});
  }
```

Spring boot controller:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/imageUpload", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>> uploadImage(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(productService.uploadImage(file), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:196) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:114) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
```

Request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary5IOZSk3ytW7tYOZ5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image/png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundary5IOZSk3ytW7tYOZ5--
```

Comment: Please check this: https://therichpost.com/how-to-upload-image-with-laravel-angular/

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886695/current-request-is-not-a-multipart-requestangular-4spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you are using `@RequestParam("image")` instead of `@RequestPart`. And consuming `"application/json"`instead of `"multipart/form-data"`. Not sure it is the problem, but only this way works for me

### Controller example:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/imageUpload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>> uploadImage(@RequestPart MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
   return new ResponseEntity<>(productService.uploadImage(image), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: I think there's a problem with angular somewhere, because in Postman i can without any problem save file, only when I try from angular app then i have an error, that is not multipart, but json i tried a lot of headers but none of them worked... i don't know why but angular still sending json not multipart